# Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to exec this query I'll get the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable

What am I doing wrong?

```
    @username varchar(50),
    @routenaam varchar(50),
    @van varchar(50),
    @naar varchar(50),
    @bezoekadres varchar(50),
    @geredenroute varchar(50),
    @karakterrit varchar(50),
    @toelichting varchar(50)
    as
    begin
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'insert into '+@username+'routeinformatie'+' values(
    @routenaam,@van,@naar,@bezoekadres,@geredenroute,@karakterrit,@toelichting)'


    EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql,N',
    @username varchar(50),
    @routenaam varchar(50),
    @van varchar(50),
    @naar varchar(50),
    @bezoekadres varchar(50),
    @geredenroute varchar(50),
    @karakterrit varchar(50),
    @toelichting varchar(50)
    ',@username@routenaam,@van,@naar,@bezoekadres,@geredenroute,@karakterrit,@toelichting
    end
```

Comment: Can you give us a clue by telling us what *name* it gives for the variable that must be declared? That should be included in the error message

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Or is this just about the missing comma in the last but one line - `@username@routenaam` should be `@username,@routenaam`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot starting DECLARE clause, and in last line you omitted comma between first two variables:

```
DECLARE   
    @username varchar(50),
    @routenaam varchar(50),
    @van varchar(50),
    @naar varchar(50),
    @bezoekadres varchar(50),
    @geredenroute varchar(50),
    @karakterrit varchar(50),
    @toelichting varchar(50)
    as
    begin
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'insert into '+@username+'routeinformatie'+' values(
    @routenaam,@van,@naar,@bezoekadres,@geredenroute,@karakterrit,@toelichting)'


    EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql,N',
    @username varchar(50),
    @routenaam varchar(50),
    @van varchar(50),
    @naar varchar(50),
    @bezoekadres varchar(50),
    @geredenroute varchar(50),
    @karakterrit varchar(50),
    @toelichting varchar(50)
    ',@username, @routenaam,@van,@naar,@bezoekadres,@geredenroute,@karakterrit,@toelichting
    end
```

Comment: Given the presence of `as` after the "variables" and before `begin`, I would assume that this is actually a stored procedure with the `CREATE PROCEDURE` line missing and so those are actually parameters (and so no `DECLARE` needed, but it doesn't help that the OPs showing us partial pieces of code)

Comment: Of course, I agree with you absolutely, but I assume that this is the first problem. Second problem can be in last line.

Comment: Yes indeed I'm editing a stored procedure. So if I want to create a new one I should do it like this? See my answer ↓.

Comment: Don't forget to accept users answer which suites to your problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to `set` the value of the variable like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @sql = N'insert into '+@username+ N'routeinformatie'+ N' values(
    @routenaam,@van,@naar,@bezoekadres,@geredenroute,@karakterrit,@toelichting)'
```

Also if this is complete query then you need to add declare at the starting

```
DECLARE @username varchar(50),
   @routenaam varchar(50),
   @van varchar(50),
   @naar varchar(50),
   @bezoekadres varchar(50),
   @geredenroute varchar(50),
   @karakterrit varchar(50),
   @toelichting varchar(50)
```

Comment: If you define a `NVARCHAR`  variable, just should use the `N'....'` notation when assigning ...

Comment: .... and you should use the `N` prefix before *every* string literal ! (also those *after* the `+@username+` part ....)

Answer (score 1):

```
    create proc insertRoute
    @username varchar(50),
    @routenaam varchar(50),
    @van varchar(50),
    @naar varchar(50),
    @bezoekadres varchar(50),
    @geredenroute varchar(50),
    @karakterrit varchar(50),
    @toelichting varchar(50)
    as
    begin
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    SET @sql = N'insert into '+@username+'routeinformatie'+' values(
    @routenaam,@van,@naar,@bezoekadres,@geredenroute,@karakterrit,@toelichting)'


    EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql,N',
    @username varchar(50),
    @routenaam varchar(50),
    @van varchar(50),
    @naar varchar(50),
    @bezoekadres varchar(50),
    @geredenroute varchar(50),
    @karakterrit varchar(50),
    @toelichting varchar(50)
    ',@username@routenaam,@van,@naar,@bezoekadres,@geredenroute,@karakterrit,@toelichting
    end
```

Making stored procedure. When I want to make it now it says:
"Must declare the scalar variable "@username@routenaam"."

Comment: You omitted comma sign in last line between `@username` and `@routenaam`. Check my answer

Comment: When you have more information to add, you should *edit* your existing question, not post the update as an *answer* - which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You must use DECLARE statement with All variable like this

```
DECLARE @username varchar(50),
   @routenaam varchar(50),
   @van varchar(50),
   @naar varchar(50),
   @bezoekadres varchar(50),
   @geredenroute varchar(50),
   @karakterrit varchar(50),
   @toelichting varchar(50)
```